# REACT.JS : Multi main Error

Tags: javascript, webpack, reactjs, package.json

i'm new with React.JS (on Windows 10 ) , i'm fulfilling a first tuto , within, i'm used to set up a basic workspace for my React.app. But after setting up webpack and babel packages globally and locally in my respository , and making a first hello word app , **the first build didn't work.**

**my pre-installation:**

```
npm install -g babel
npm install -g babel-cli
npm install webpack --save
npm install webpack-dev-server --save
npm install react --save
npm install react-dom --save
npm install babel-core
npm install babel-loader
npm install babel-preset-react
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

consequently my **package.json** contains :

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

my repository contains 4 other files : 
index.html , App.jsx , main.js , webpack.config.js

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "index.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

**App.jsx :**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

**main.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8123
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

so whenever i'm launching "npm start "  i'm getting a failed build (the capture -attached-)

[image]

and similarly , on localhost:8123 , i'm getting a same error like below:
[image]

***Any suggestion to resolve that ??***

Comment: `entry: "./main.js"`

Comment: yeah it was that , but it still not working

Comment: could it be that it tries to reload your main.js afterwards as the target for the build is in the same path as your sourcecode? Why not put your entry and source files in a separate directory so webpack doesn't get confused afterwards

Comment: yeah just fixing that and re-install the node modules , fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ve simply resolved it by deleting the **node_modules** folder , and retaping **npm install**